# graceful-fs warning when running Grunt task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm getting this warning when running one of my grunt tasks:

```
Warning: (node:2771) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
```

Does somebody know how to get rid of that? And how to find it's source? My nodejs version is 6.0.0.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: This is a warning that the program will break in Node 7. See https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5102. A dependency is probably using graceful-fs@<4.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your best option right now is to downgrade to the latest Node 5.x until that dependency has been updated.

Suggest that you read: [DON'T rush to upgrade to Node v6](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dont-rush-to-upgrade-to-node-v6/50657) and [Breaking changes between v5 and v6](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v5-and-v6).

We all want to be on the latest and greatest - myself included. A great way to do this is to use something like [n](https://github.com/tj/n) or [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to quickly flip between Node versions so that we can use Node v6 on some projects and older versions on other projects.

The other thing that I do is I put a package like [Node Version Checker](https://github.com/gobold/node-version-checker) in my project and use it in both the tests and the application to make sure that I've changed to the expected version of Node when I start the project or the tests as we often forget to flip to the right version of Node if we have multiple versions on multiple projects.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using homebrew here is how you can downgrade to v5.11.0

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew unlink node
brew install homebrew/versions/node5
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: I had to run `brew tap homebrew/versions` before, but this worked for me. If/when you'd like to go back to the current version of node, just run the reverse, i.e., `brew unlink homebrew/versions/node5` then `brew link node`

Answer (score 2):

after update to node6 have the same issue.
working workaround downgrade, e.g. nvm use v5.11.0